# MySQL count(*) has to return 0 when no entries

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch a list of amount of visits each month from my `tracking` table.

I use the following query:

```
SELECT MONTH(TimeStamp) AS month, COUNT(*) AS Amount FROM tracking WHERE YEAR(TimeStamp)=2021 GROUP BY MONTH(TimeStamp)
```

I wish to have a result something like this, for example, there are no TimeStamps on January, February and March:

```
month Amount
----- ------
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     18
5     2
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     3
10    2
11    5
12    3
```

But my query gives this, with January, February and March not showing:

```
month Amount
----- ------
4     18
5     2
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     3
10    2
11    5
12    3
```

When there are no records found it should give a 0 in the output. How can I achieve this?

Example of 1 row in my table:

```
TrackingID | UserID | Scan
    1          3       2021-04-04 18:14:00
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a simple query, like this, working on MySQL, MariaDB, TSQL:

```
SELECT m.month, COALESCE(t.n, 0) as Amount FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS month
     UNION SELECT 2
     UNION SELECT 3
     UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5
     UNION SELECT 6
     UNION SELECT 7
     UNION SELECT 8
     UNION SELECT 9
     UNION SELECT 10
     UNION SELECT 11
     UNION SELECT 12
  ) m
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n, MONTH(TimeStamp) AS month
    FROM tracking
    WHERE YEAR(TimeStamp)=2021
    GROUP BY MONTH(TimeStamp)
  ) t
  ON m.month=t.month
  ORDER BY m.month;
```

The first SELECT with UNION creates a list of month values in [1,12] in fly without requring a temporary table, it is aliased as `m` for 12 months.

The second SELECT aliased as `t` for tracking, counts amount of records for year 2021, grouped by month.

The two parts are then joined with "LEFT JOIN" in order to list nonexistent months in tracking table.

This gives in my test table, something like this:

[image]

---

## MySQL 8.0.19+

If you have MySQL 8.0.19 or later, `UNION SELECT` can be replace by [VALUES Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html), the above query can be simplified as thus:

```
SELECT m.column_0 AS month, COALESCE(t.n, 0) as Amount FROM
  (VALUES ROW(1),ROW(2),ROW(3),ROW(4),ROW(5),ROW(6),
    ROW(7),ROW(8),ROW(9),ROW(10),ROW(11),ROW(12)
  ) m
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n, MONTH(TimeStamp) AS month
    FROM tracking
    WHERE YEAR(TimeStamp)=2021
    GROUP BY MONTH(TimeStamp)
  ) t
  ON m.column_0=t.month
  ORDER BY m.column_0;
```

We remark that MySQL VALUES Statement names columns column_0, column_1, column_2, and so on.

---

## MariaDB 10.3+

Linux Debian MariaDB uses another syntax for [VALUES statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/table-value-constructors/). Our query can be written as this:

```
SELECT m.1 AS month, COALESCE(t.n, 0) as Amount FROM
  (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),
    (7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
  ) m
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n, MONTH(TimeStamp) AS month
    FROM tracking
    WHERE YEAR(TimeStamp)=2021
    GROUP BY MONTH(TimeStamp)
  ) t
  ON m.1=t.month
  ORDER BY m.1;
```

Comment: yes, but remember you can use `VALUES ROW(1), ... ROW(12)` instead of all those union statements.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

Comment: @Hogan, thanks you for your points, my query works also on Transact-SQL server. I'll test your method.

Comment: the syntax for VALUES is different on TSQL (and better).  DB2 has the best syntax for it IMO

Comment: Thanks it works! Is there a more efficient way of doing this or is this the one and only solution?

Comment: @Hogan, in  8.0.17 MySQL, VALUES does not work. I've no MySQL v8.0.19 on Windows. Neither on mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2.

Comment: @jacouh -- values is an SQL standard so it is not unreasonable to point it out to readers since in the future people reading this will be able to use it.

Comment: @hogan, OK I'll add it after some testing...

Comment: MySQL 8.0+ (and MariaDB) also has the [WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) statement ....

Comment: @Luuk, thanks, I've installed MySQL 8.0.23, tested VALUES statement working.